# How to get a list[String] from a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file in HDFS with a list of ids that I want to read as a list of String. When I do this

```
spark.read.text(filePath).collect.toList
```

I get a List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] instead. How do I read this file into a list of string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `spark.read.textFile(filepath)` instead, you will get a `DataSet[String]` instead of a `DataFrame` (aka, `DataSet[Row]`).  Then when you collect you will get an `Array[String]` instead of `Array[Row]`.

You can also convert a `DataFrame` with a single string column into a `DataSet[String]` using `df.as[String]`. So `df.as[String].collect` will get an `Array[String]` from a `DataFrame` (assuming the `DataFrame` contains a single string column, otherwise this will fail)

Answer (score 3):

Use `map(_.getString(0))` to extract the value from the Row object:

```
spark.read.text(filePath).map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList
```